# Finding the equation of a circle given three tangent line equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

How do you find the equation of a circle given three tangent line equations?

Given :

4x + 2y = 8

4x + 2y = 4

and

2x - 4y = -10

thankyou!

Comment: The center $(p,q)$ should be at equal [distances from each line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation). That gives you two equations with two unknowns. Expect to get [up to four solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Excircles_and_excenters).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The first two lines are parallel to each other, which should enable you to compute the diameter/radius of the circle. The third line is perpendicular to the first two lines. Draw a picture.