# Incenter of a triangle formed by three lines.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangle-centres

How can we find the incenter of a triangle (without using its vertices) that is formed by three lines  $y=m_1x + c_1,  
y=m_2x + c_2,   y=m_3x + c_3$?

Comment: Strange handicap, but one way could be the plan in the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3423171/713897).

Answer (score 1):

As in the solution referred to in the comment by @conditionalMethod, the incentre $(u.v)$ must be equidistant from the three lines.

The distance, $d$ say, then satisfies

$$d=\frac{|m_iu-v+c_i|}{\sqrt{m_i^2+1}}.$$

We can express these equations neatly as

$$\begin{pmatrix}-m_1&1&\sqrt{m_1^2+1} \\-m_2&1&\pm \sqrt{m_2^2+1}\\-m_3&1&\pm  \sqrt{m_3^2+1}\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u \\v\\*\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\c_2\\c_3\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Given values for the $m_i,c_i$ these equations can be solved for $u,v$ in a mechanical manner.
A drawback of this method is that the incircle is obtained for only one choice of the +/-. Looking positively at this though, you get the bonus of the equations of the 3 excircles from the other choices.

Comment: Clever. ... Your $d$ formula gives a *signed* distance to the line, however, so it's not clear (to me) how to guarantee the incircle instead of an excircle.

Comment: @Blue Yes - a very good point. Probably the simplest thing with given constants is to see which side of each line should be used and change  signs  accordingly. I'll think about modifying the answer!